# How to create unscubscribe functionality to let user unsubscribe from in-app subscription purchase?

Tags: ios, ios6

I am building code to let a user subscribe to an in-app purchase subscription.

But I do not see any tutorials or examples (even from the official site) to let the user unsubscribe. Could anyone please point me to a tutorial for this, or please explain how users can unsubscribe from my in-app subscriptions?

Thank you@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.  Users have to go to iTunes and set the subscription to not auto-renew themselves.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Just to clarify - so the developers never have to do anything to handle the case of unsubscribing?

Comment: You need to check the in-app purchase receipts and verify that the user has a valid subscription, then provide the subscription content.  But you do not have to (and cannot) provide a way to unsubscribe.